# Event Coding Keyboard Input

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, event-handling, pygame, raspberry-pi3

I am coding with python on my raspberry pi. Python isn't my best language so bear with me.

I need a simple code that responds to key strokes on my keyboard. I'd doing this so I can set the Pulse Width Modulation, but I don't need that code, I already have it. My main concern is I am struggling to understand the `pygame` functionality required for my task.

I would like to be able to type a key, such as "up arrow" <kbd>↑</kbd> and have the program output `"up pressed"` for every millisecond the up arrow is pressed.

The pseudo-code would look like:

```
double x = 1
while x == 1:
    if input.key == K_UP:
        print("Up Arrow Pressed")
    if input.key == K_q
        x = 2
    wait 1ms

pygame.quit()
```

Again I have no clue what to import or call due to not knowing the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that will check if the <kbd>↑</kbd> key is pressed:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([320,240])

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        print("Up Arrow Pressed")
    elif keys[pygame.K_q]:
        done = True

    clock.tick(1000)

pygame.quit()
```

Note that [clock.tick(1000)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) will *limit* the code to one-thousand frames per second, so won't exactly equate to your desired 1 millisecond delay. On my PC I only see a frame rate of around six-hundred.

Perhaps you should be looking at the key down and key up events and toggle your output then?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([320,240])

done = False
output = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                output = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                output = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                done = True

    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Output Status {output}")
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

If you run this, you'll see the title of the window change whilst the <kbd>↑</kbd> key is pressed.